# one of dual monitors not showing correct resolution by default

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

Hoping someone can help me with my situation. I have two `Asus PB287Q monitors` connected to my `GTX 680 desktop`.

One is connected via a dual-link dvi port and getting the 2560x1440 resolution by default. The other is using a HDMI 1.4 supported cable but only gets 1920x1080 resolution.
 I know that it can support 2560x1440 as my Windows 7 install picks up the resolution at 60Hz no problem over the HDMI.

How I can fix this?

Current install setup:

```
Dual boot ubuntu 14.04/Windows 7   
Latest Nvidia drivers
```

Answer (score 0):

see this link..
12.04 did not work, then 13.10 did work but now 14.04 does not work

link is here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1404557#p1404557

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.